# How to permanently redirect port 8080 URL to port 80 using nginx

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

Because of my carelessness, I put http://www.domain.com:8080/xxx/index.html on the internet.  I don't want to lose that traffic, so i want to permanent redirect that url to 
http://www.domain.com/xxx/index.html
Can nginx achieve this?
thanks

Comment: Click the check mark under the answer that was the best.

Answer (score 4):

```
server {
    listen www.domain.com:8080;
    server_name  www.domain.com;
    rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com permanent;    
}
```

Should do it.

Comment: Unless you really need the extra folder path - /xxx/index.html

Comment: in which case rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com$request_uri permanent; would do it.