# How can I redirect a port number on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, port

I have a Tomcat application running on my Linux machine on port 8080 (`www.myapplication.com:8080/myapps`).

I want to redirect the Tomcat port `:8080` to the default HTTP port of `:80` so that the application can be accesed without a port number (`www.myapplication.com/myapps`).

How can I do that on Linux?

Comment: Why not just update tomcat configuration to listen on 80 instead of 8080?

Answer (score 7):

You could use `iptables` to redirect port 80 to 8080.

This is useful if your application is started by an unprivileged user instead of root.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080
```

HTH,
PEra

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/444729/929 (i.e. you might have to use `OUTPUT` instead of `PREROUTING`)

Answer (score 2):

There so many ways to achieve this, but first which comes to my mind is to use `nginx`: [How to permanently redirect port 8080 URL to port 80 using nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/180800/how-to-permanently-redirect-port-8080-url-to-port-80-using-nginx)

Another one is to use `iptables`: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-port-redirection-with-iptables/

Comment: Thanks php-coder...Its sloved my problem..I executed on command and its worked for me...:)

Answer (score 2):

You should never face the Tomcat or any other Java application server to the external world. The best practice is to install Apache HTTPD and use it a reverse proxy to wrap Tomcat or JBoss.

I recommend to do the following.

1. Install **httpd**:

   ```
   yum install httpd
   ```
2. Create file

   ```
   /etc/httpd/conf.d/myredirect.conf
   ```

   with the following content:

   ```
   ProxyPass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapps/
   ProxyPassReverse       http://127.0.0.1:8080/myapps/
   ```
3. If the application resides in the root than the configuration will be the following:

   ```
   ProxyPass   http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ProxyPassReverse       http://127.0.0.1:8080/
   ```
4. Restart **httpd**:

   ```
   service httpd restart
   ```

The instructions above are provided for RedHat-family linux. They may differ for other ones.

Comment: Why not let java face the world?

Answer (score 1):

first you should change server.xml file, change "Connector port="8080" " to "80". the file may be at /etc/tomcat6, or you could use "locate server.xml" to find it.

second you should change the default tomcat6 configure file, in my system (debian squeeze) is /etc/default/tomcat6, add the line: AUTHBIND=yes.

restart your tomcat.

then you can use www.myapplication.com/myapps to access your app.

Answer (score 0):

For a really quick, temporary, swiss-army-knife utility-type solution that likely doesn't require installing anything at all:

In another terminal, while already logged into the machine, open an ssh port forwarding session to localhost, like so:

```
$  ssh -L:1111:localhost:2222 localhost
```

You should expect to see the following (or at least the first line). You may need to supply your password.

```
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
```

The above will forward traffic for port 1111 into port 2222.

So, in the OP's case:

```
$  ssh -L:8080:localhost:80 localhost
```